# How do you remove a nested dictionary(map) from Firestore?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make a method that removes a nested dictionary from my firebase database. The documentation says to use FieldValue.delete() but that only works for dictionaries on the first level. Setting the key equal to nil doesn't work either; this changes its value to "null" in firebase, but doesn't delete it.

```
database
    .collection("users")
    .document(userID)
    .updateData([
        "dict1":[
            "dict2":***thisIsTheValueINeedToDelete***
        ]
    ])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FieldValue.delete()` works for nested maps as well.  You will need to use the dot notation to call out the full path of the nested map.

```
.updateData(["dict1.dict2": FieldValue.delete()])
```

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to do it for paths where the dot notation is illegal? (For example, if the key has "/" in it)